# bind in and out parameters to anonymous pl/sql

Tags: binding, plsql, oracle11g, anonymous

I have a problem which I cant seem to find if Oracle allows it or not. I have an anonymous PL/SQL block which intends to do a

1. SELECT using some WHERE clauses in which values are not fixed but determined at runtime
2. then from a set of rows returned it picks one which matches and UPDATES it.
3. Finally the intention is to pass the UPDATED rows columns back to the application

I am not fully sure how to

a_ pass parameters/bind variables into an "**anonymous** PL/SQL block
b_ get a row or even an id back from the **anonymous** PL/SQL block (step 3 above).

While I get that it is possible to do for a named stored procedure or function - I am getting unclear response if a and b are possible for an **anonymous** pl/sql.

Here is a representative code:

```
DECLARE
     n1 NUMBER ;
     n2 NUMBER ;
     rid UROWID;
     CURSOR c IS SELECT rowid from MY_TABLE WHERE colA= n1;
     row MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
   OPEN c;  
   FETCH c INTO rid;
   LOOP
       SELECT * INTO row FROM MY_TABLE where rowid=rid FOR UPDATE;
       IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
          CONTINUE;
       ELSE
          UPDATE MY_TABLE SET colZ= n2 WHERE rowid = rid;
          IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 1 THEN
                 // need to return  value of row back to application
          END IF;
       END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Here is what I am looking for (specifically for anonymous pl/sql)
 - I am looking for n1 and n2 to be set as bind variables or input arguments by the calling application. 
 - Also I am looking if the row updated can be sent back after pl/sql block execution.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: Anonymous PL/SQL block can't have input or output parameters nor it can't return a value. Instead use your host environment bind variables. In case of sqlplus please see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11738090 and http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/use_vars.html

Comment: user272735 could you please expand on using "host environment bind variable"? How would that work?

Comment: @john-saunders , added sample code just now

Comment: What part of the links you don't understand ? The host environment is the environment/context where the anonymous PL/SQL block is executed. Are you using sqlplus (the right way) to execute the block or some bloated GUI or JAVA code over JDBC or something else ?

Comment: @user272735 I am using two applications - one c++ using OCI probably (not sure: hidden by my framework code) and one java using jdbc. I need to run plsql in both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well thanks to @user272735 hinting about bind variables. I explored a bit further and found that I could use callable statement which will also take positional parameters for input and also for output.

so, the above plsql would become (in java code).

```
//see how to use multiline literals in java; kept here without quotes for clarity
// note n1 and n2 are commented as they can be bound as in parameters in the host env.
// also note that input and output parameters are replaced by ?

String sql = "DECLARE
     -- n1 NUMBER ;
     -- n2 NUMBER ;
     rid UROWID;
     CURSOR c IS SELECT rowid from MY_TABLE WHERE colA= ?;
     row MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
   OPEN c;  
   FETCH c INTO rid;
   LOOP
       SELECT * INTO row FROM MY_TABLE where rowid=rid FOR UPDATE;
       IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
          CONTINUE;
       ELSE
          UPDATE MY_TABLE SET colZ= ? WHERE rowid = rid;
          IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 1 THEN
                 SELECT  colP INTO ? from MY_TABLE where rowid = rid;
          END IF;
       END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;";
CallableStatement cst = conn.prepareCall(sql);
cst.setBigDecimal(1,new BigDecimal(n1)); //this is the first input parameter
cst.setBigDecimal(2,new BigDecimal(n2)); // this is the second input parameter 
cst.registerOutParameter(3,0); // this is the third parameter to be used for output

cst.executeUpdate();

String s = cst.getString(3); // for the third parameter which is also the out parameter
```

Comment: Consider replacing UPDATE + SELECT with single [atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930704/oracle-pl-sql-is-update-returning-concurrent) [UPDATE RETURNING  INTO](http://psoug.org/snippet/UPDATE-with-RETURNING-clause_604.htm) statement.

Comment: Moreover, the whole cursor loop can be replaced with single [update top 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468067/how-to-update-top-n-rows-dynamically) statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind variables as input for the anonymous block.
But there is no way to return the any value from an anonymous block.

Even when you have a RETURN statement, which can be used in the block. This statement is just used to quit the block, rather than sending any value as output.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS99896